# Bootstrap navbar link color won't change

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I need to change my navbar links to white and space them out across the navbar. I have written code for this but I can't seem to figure out why/where it keeps getting overridden. The background of the navbar is an image and the links seem to change to white without the image in there, so is there a way to fix that and keep the image in the background?

Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

```css
.navbar {
  background-image: url("images/navbarbgnew.png");
  background-size: cover;
  margin: -30px 0 15px 0;
}

.navbar ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.navbar ul li a {
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: "Helvetica," sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light mb-3">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          BOOKS
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Branding Sutra</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          LEARNING LAB
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Workshops</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Classes</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Audio Downloads</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">SERVICES</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: @Mast You opened a bounty. Why? What is still unclear?

Comment: @WebDevBooster Nothing. "One or more of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty." I ran into the same problem as OP today and your answer fixed it. Have some rep. Simply takes 24h before I can award it.

Comment: @Mast Aha. Thanks mate!

Comment: This is a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48735679/bootstrap-change-navbar-link-colors

Comment: @ZimSystem a duplicate and answered by the same person the same day ! how this one avoided your Boostrap hammer ?:p

Comment: @ZimSystem The answer on this one looks better IMO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

The specificity of your custom css rule must **either match or exceed the specificity of the corresponding Bootstrap rule**.

So, in this particular case you need a rule that looks like this:

```
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color: red;
}
```

Click "run code snippet" button below and expand to full page to verify that it works:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
<style>
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color: red;
}
</style>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light mb-3">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    BOOKS
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Branding Sutra</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    LEARNING LAB
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Workshops</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Classes</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Audio Downloads</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">SERVICES</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

More info about CSS specificity:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

And: [CSS Specificity Calculator](https://specificity.keegan.st)

Comment: thank you! it was partly answered. it changed the links to white, but they're still bunched on the left side of the navbar. How do I space them out across the entire width? I thought display:flex and justify-content: space-around; would do that?

Comment: @brihep if you're using bootstrap, just add the class `ms-auto` to every single `<li>` item

Answer (score 0):

just remove the class= navbar-light;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31158145)