# Bootstrap 4 can't change font color in navbar menu

Tags: bootstrap-4

Tried everything and for some reason I can't change colour of font in navbar menu. It's stays black no matter what I do.

```
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <a href="index.html"><img src="images/finfab-logo.jpg" alt="Company logo"></a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
              <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item active">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                </ul>

            </div>
          </nav>
```

This is how style look now but tried few other options too. I'm out of ideas at this stage.

```css
.jumbotron{
  background-color: #003300;
}

.nav-item{
  font-size: 25px;
  color:#003300;
}
```

Comment: I have answered your question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48730183/8270343

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to put the !important command on your css styles where you change the font? As you need it to overwrite the styles of bootstrap in that case.
So it would be:

```
color: #003300 !important;
```

Comment: I tried. Didn't work. The only way of changing color is to use contextual colours but that's not what I want.

Comment: Have you also tried removing the navbar-light class? Maybe that influences the font color.

Comment: The `!important` flag should **never** be used as a permanent solution. It's for testing purposes only.

Comment: If used as a last resort, this answer seems useful enough.